# How to move cursor one line down with API in the way like the default 'j'?

Tags: neovim, lua

For example, I have this in the buffer:

```
line1 .... A ....
line2 B
line3 .... C ....
```

Follow these steps:

1. At first it's in Normal mode and the cursor is under `A`
2. Press `j` and the cursor will move to `B`
3. Press `j` again and the cursor will move to `C`

Seems like internally Vim maintains a "user-expected" column position so when it goes from line2 to line3 it smartly restores the correct column position.

So how can I get the same behavior with **Lua API** <sup>(like `vim.api.nvim_win_set_cursor()`)</sup> when moving the cursor one line down?

Comment: Idk about Lua, but `:normal! j` would probably work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As reminded by @D.Ben's comment, the following workaround works for me:

```lua
vim.cmd('norm! j')
```

Comment: The bang matters; without it, you’re command invokes whatever `j` is mapped to

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thanks for the info. updated.